# C# Windows Forms, How can dynamic events be generated on dynamic buttons?

Tags: c#, windows, events, dynamic

```
    //
    int c = 1;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Button AddNewButton()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Button btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Top = 350;
        btn.Left = c * 80;
        btn.Text = "" + this.c.ToString();
        btn.Name = "MButton" + this.c.ToString();
        c = c + 1;
        return btn;
    }
    //

AddNewButton();
AddNewButton();
.
.
.
AddNewButton();
// Create the button through the for statement.
```

I dynamically generate buttons.
When I click the generated button 1
Console.WriteLine("Click_Button1");

When I click the generated button 2
Console.WriteLine("Click_Button2");
.
.
.
When I click the generated button 50
Console.WriteLine("Click_Button50");

---

In this way I want to create a dynamic event.
How can I generate a dynamic event?

Comment: Maybe `btn.Click += (s.e) => { Console.WriteLine("Button {0}", c); };` but it is a bit weird to have a winforms app that writes its messages to a console. Not impossible, just odd.

Comment: I think you have to better understand the concepts of delegate and event handler. You can start by reading this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/event-handling-in-net-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ClickEventHandler while creation of the button

```
btn.Click += (sender,e)=>{Console.WriteLine("Click_Button"+1)};
```

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers can be added to controls and classes programmatically via the following syntax

```
myButton.Click += myButton_Click;

void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message here");
        this.Close();
    }
```